# SQL Server nested cursor problem

Tags: sql-server, nested, cursor, dblink

I have a strange problem with my nested cursors and I have no idea what it's all about.

Here's my T-SQL code:

```
declare @dbname varchar(50)
declare @servername varchar(50)
declare srv cursor for select servername from test.dbo.servers
declare @str varchar(200)

truncate table test.dbo.temp

open srv
fetch next from srv into @servername
while @@fetch_status = 0   
begin   
   set @str = 'Data Source='+@servername+';Integrated Security=SSPI'   
   declare db cursor for select name from opendatasource('SQLNCLI', @str).master.dbo.sysdatabases
   open db
   fetch next from db into @dbname
   while @@fetch_status = 0
   begin
      insert test.dbo.temp (dbname, servername) values (@dbname, @servername)
      fetch next from db into @dbname
   end
   fetch next from srv into @servername
   close db
   deallocate db
end   
close srv
deallocate srv
```

It gives me next error message:

> Incorrect syntax near '@str'.
>   [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102)

Looks like the problem is in giving the variable as a parameter to opendatasource function. But why? And how to avoid this problem?

Comment: *nested cursor* : that's your problem right there!!

Comment: @marc_s I think that a nested cursor is the only viable way of doing what the OP wants to do (loop through all databases in a collection of servers, the names of which are contained in a table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that variables cannot be passed to `OPENDATASOURCE`.  Instead You must use a literal instead.  As much as we discourage using dynamic SQL, there are some cases that it is unavoidable.  Try something like this:

```
declare @dbname varchar(50)
declare @servername varchar(50)
declare srv cursor for select servername from test.dbo.servers
declare @str varchar(200)
declare @sql nvarchar(MAX)

truncate table test.dbo.temp

open srv
fetch next from srv into @servername
while @@fetch_status = 0   
begin
   SET @sql = N'
   declare db cursor for select name from opendatasource(''SQLNCLI'', ''Data Source='+@servername+';Integrated Security=SSPI'').master.dbo.sysdatabases
   open db
   fetch next from db into @dbname
   while @@fetch_status = 0
   begin
      insert test.dbo.temp (dbname, servername) values (@dbname, @servername)
      fetch next from db into @dbname
   end
   close db
   deallocate db
   '
   EXEC sp_executesql
    @sql,
    N'@dbname     varchar(50),
      @servername varchar(50)',
    @dbname,
    @servername

   fetch next from srv into @servername
end   
close srv
deallocate srv
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't thought that way! :) 
it's really helped!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use nested cursors, you are doing something wrong.  There are very few reasons to use a cursor instead of some other set-based operation, and using a cursor within a cursor is like the ultimate SQL Server anti-pattern.

For your inner cursor, you could change it to use the undocumented `sp_msforeachdb` function *(which apparently creates a cursor behind the scenes)*:

```
open srv
fetch next from srv into @servername
while @@fetch_status = 0   
begin
 EXEC sp_msforeachdb '
 Data Source='+@servername+';Integrated Security=SSPI
 insert test.dbo.temp (dbname, servername) values (?, @Servername)'
 fetch next from srv into @servername
end   
close srv
deallocate srv
```

You may need to enclose the ? in single quotes  and escape them, like:

`EXEC sp_msforeachdb 'insert test.dbo.temp (dbname, servername) values (''?'', @Servername)`

Comment: er, I take it that you haven't looked at the definition of `sp_msforeachdb` then? (It uses a cursor!)

Comment: @Martin - lol I didn't know that's how it operated internally.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: @JNK - I guess there may be an argument for using it still though (+1). It takes some of the complexity out of the OP's code and does some additional checks that the database is accessible.

Comment: I like that you use `sp_msforeachdb`, but I'm not sure how this makes the connections to the remote servers.

Comment: @Phil - Good point, I erroneously left that out.  Corrected above.